# Android File.listFiles does not show all the files inside the directory

Tags: android

I am using Android Emulator 2.2 version to develop a small application. I am supposed to list all the image files(jpg) files under a directory. I copied the files to "/data" through ADB puash command.

Example : /data/1.jpg

Now I create a File object with the directory path as input and call listFiles api.

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
```

But the fileList does not contain the image file(1.jpg).

But strangely, If I create a ImageView with hardcoded path "/data/1.jpg", I could see the image getting drawn.

Can some one help me.... where could be the problem

Thanks,
Kowndinya

---

```
public int PopulateList(final String dirPath)
{
    m_CurrentDirectory = new File(dirPath);
    _namelist.clear();
    _pathlist.clear();

    File[] fileList = m_CurrentDirectory.listFiles(imFilter);
    if (fileList != null)
    {
        for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++)
        {
            _namelist.addElement(fileList[i].getName());
            _pathlist.addElement(fileList[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return 0;
}
```

imFilter is an filenamefilter that accepts only files with jpg extension. But if I put break point in the imFilter code, break point does not event hit.

```
Output of adb shell ls -l /data:
------------------------------------
drwxrwx--t system   misc              2010-08-05 15:32 misc
drwxrwx--x shell    shell             2010-08-05 15:32 local
drwxrwx--x system   system            2010-08-05 15:32 app-private
drwx------ system   system            2010-08-05 15:34 backup
drwx------ root     root              2010-08-05 15:34 property
drwxrwx--x system   system            2010-08-05 15:35 data
-rw-rw-rw- root     root        75752 2010-03-30 12:26 zona_ind_012.jpg
drwxrwx--x system   system            2010-08-05 16:16 app
drwxr-x--- root     log               2010-08-05 15:32 dontpanic
drwxrwx--x system   system            2010-08-05 16:25 dalvik-cache
drwxrwxr-x system   system            2010-08-05 17:16 system
drwxrwx--- root     root              2010-08-05 15:32 lost+found
```

Answer (score 3):

I explore that code, and see, trouble is in permission. As you can see below, you can't read that dir.Find another dir to collect your files.

```
**Can read dir:** 
/dev =true
/root =false
/data =false
/default.prop =true
/init =false
/init.rc =false
/proc =true
/sbin =false
/sys =true
/system =true
/etc =true
/d =false
/mnt =true
/acct =true
/sdcard =true
/cache =false
/config =false
```

and that you can see from "ls -l" command. 
[explain what does mean](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml)