# Why listFiles() returns only folders but not files

Tags: java, android

Why listFiles() returns only folders but not files
this is my code

```
File f  = new File("/sdcard/Download");
File[] list = f.listFiles();
    
        if(list!=null) {
          Log.e("exists",f.exists()+"");
          Log.e("isDirectory",f.isDirectory()+"");
          Log.e("getPath",f.getPath() +"");
          Log.e("length",f.listFiles().length+"");
              
          for (File fil : list) {
            Log.e("name", fil.getName());
          }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: see same question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414100/android-file-listfiles-does-not-show-all-the-files-inside-the-directory

Comment: This happens only on an Android 11+ device.

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,  new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},  111); This solved the problem. Permission in Manifest doesn't work in this case.

Comment: It does. As your runtime code request cannot do without.